# R Cricketdata Package

Tags: r

I am using the `fetch_cricinfo` function of R package `Cricketdata` and getting an error

```
fetch_cricinfo("test", "Men", "Batting",type="innings", country = "Ind")
```

**Error:**

```
Error in cli::cli_progress_update() : 
  Cannot find current progress bar for `<environment: 0x000002d0a2a69d10>`
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug. There was a [bug fix](https://github.com/robjhyndman/cricketdata/commit/dedb9d26a05accda745415935263d0f57c141a2b) for `cli_progress_bar()` from two months ago so it's probably related. Very annoying as it's not even essential for the data. For me, it runs up 98% then I get the same error as you. I recommend you log a bug report [here](https://github.com/robjhyndman/cricketdata/issues).

Comment: I installed a new version of cricketdata package using the below command and it works perfectly:

devtools::install_github("robjhyndman/cricketdata")